# Address of entity used in fetch request does not match address of entity in relationship when it should

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a method for destroying outdated NSManagedObjects called messages:

```
+ (void)syncMessagesByIDs:(NSArray *)messageIDs toGroup:(Group *)group context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    // This is getting all the Messages that still have a relationship to this Group but
    // are not in our passed in set of messages and therefor should be removed
    // from the Group.
    NSPredicate *searchTerm = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ IN %K) && NOT (%K in %@)", group, @"groups", @"id_number", messageIDs];
    NSArray *results = [Message fetchManyWithPredicate:searchTerm context:context];

    for (Message *message in results) {
        DLog(@"message.groups %d", message.groups.count);
        [message removeGroupsObject:group];
        if (message.groups.count == 0) {
            [context deleteObject:message];
        }
    }
}


+ (NSArray *)fetchManyWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass(self) inManagedObjectContext:context];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;

    NSArray *results = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }

    [fetchRequest release];

    return results;
}
```

Oddly, I have results returned for my fetch. This implies that there are a set of messages that have a relationship to the group which I used for the query BUT do not have an id_number in the array of messageIDs.

However, when I print message.groups from the console I get **0x1f83c740** as the address of the group that matches the group in my query, but the group in my query has an address of **0x1fe99db0**, two different addresses.

Because the addresses of the group in my query and the group in the relationship are different my call to `[message removeGroupsObject:group]` does nothing.

Why could this be happening?

**More Info:**

If it helps, this call is made in a background thread with a context of NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.

The following code also returns a group with a different address than both of the other groups previously shown.

```
searchTerm = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", group];
NSArray *groupResults = [RDGroup fetchManyWithPredicate:searchTerm context:context];
DLog(@"groupsResults: %@", groupResults);
```

I'm getting the same group with a different address every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wups! I looked down the call stack and just realized my Group entity was never created in the thread of the context I'm using for the fetch request. I needed to pass in the objectID of the Group and create a new Group in the correct context.

I'm curious to why an exception wasn't thrown for accessing an entity outside of the context that owns it though.

Hope this helps anyone else in the future!